# mongoose aggregate sort does not work properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

the $sort method in this query does not work properly, I want to list aggregations and they should be listed depending on $sort query I defined

```
const newConverSation = await Messenger.Messenger.aggregate([
    { 
        $sort: { 'createdAt': -1 } 
    },
    { $match: {
        users: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userid)}},
        {
      $group: {
        _id: { $setUnion: "$users" },
        message: { $first: "$$ROOT" },
      },
    },
  ])
```

It sometimes sort correctly, sometimes does not, randomly...

--------------------------------edited for another question

this is my toJSON method which normally works properly

```
messengerScheme.methods.toJSON = function(){
const messenger = this
const messengerObject = messenger.toObject()
messengerObject.createdAt = moment(messengerObject.createdAt).fromNow()
return messengerObject
```

}

when I query my model directly I get `createdAt : "7 hours"`, However when I query it with such an aggregation I get createdAt : "2021-05-17T11:34:47.475Z", so toJSON method does not work in my aggregation

Comment: You may want to include a sample input document - someone can take a look at it try to help.

Comment: the $group stage does not guaranty to preserve same order as previous stage, you need to sort order after `$group` stage.

Comment: @turivishal thanks man, you saved my life twice , it has worked but there is one last issue I might ask, toJSON method in my Messenger model also does not work in this aggregation process, How can I activate it ?

Comment: can you show what is the issue..

Comment: @turivishal I've edited the post , thanks

Comment: see this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wJUghVAY08S) try 2 more stage after `$group` stage. and then your method will work..

Comment: @turivishal It sorts by time correctly however, It does not trigger toJSON method of the model